# How old were the rebels, Wedge and Biggs?

Tags: age, final-fantasy

How old were the members of the rebellion, Wedge and Biggs, at the time we first meet them, helping the rebels' bombing mission which successfully hit the reactor?

---

<sub>Any similarity to recent questions about [Finn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn), [Rey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115010/how-old-is-rey), [Han](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115738/how-old-is-han), [Luke](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115312/how-old-is-luke), [Mace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115796/how-old-is-mace), [Tarkin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115802/how-old-is-tarkin) and [Chewie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117723/how-old-is-chewie) is, of course, entirely co-incidental.</sub>

---

[Biggs and Wedge](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Biggs_and_Wedge_(Final_Fantasy_VII)) have been recurring character-names throughout the Final Fantasy series - I'm particularly interested in the FFVII incarnation. Apparently their backstories are being expanded in the upcoming [Final Fantasy VII remake](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2015/12/15/biggs-wedge-jessie-final-fantasy-vii-remake/).

They were very likeable members of the rebellion against Shinra, and seemed like niave, idealistic youths who don't quite realise what they've got themselves into. But how old were they really, at the time of the rebellion against Shinra in FFVII?

Comment: They've been recurring names, not recurring characters.

Comment: Did you try on purpose to get star wars character names?

Comment: The English translations of FF have many hidden references, Easter eggs, tongue in cheek jokes, and so on including things like Wedge and Biggs's names.